# Font Awesome Icons not displaying anymore (2020)

Tags: font-awesome

I checked my code for missing semicolons in the styles and missing brackets in the html but everything looks fine but the Font Awesome icons are not displaying.

For example, there are supposed to be down carets at the end of every navigation item in the second navigation bar.

When I inspected the page, the icons are still in the DOM but I do get this error in the console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().

Can someone please help me figure out what is going on here? I don't think it's my code, I think it's something to do with Font Awesome but I could be wrong.

EDIT: Upon further inspection, it seems that all of my font awesome icons have a 0 width value. Not sure why.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/connorocampo/pen/ZEGYvJZ?editors=1000)

Here is my kit code:
`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2641fe0f3e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Just had the same thing. It was an error at Font Awesome's side - something to do with an AWS S3 bucket being incorrect.  It is back online for me.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested my script in a different pen and it worked. Then rechecked my original pen. Thanks.